# Visual Studio Code: DesignHostManager failed

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I'm trying to setup a project and I get the following error in the output `OmniSharpLog`

```
[ERROR:OmniSharp.Dnx.DesignTimeHostManager] Failed to launch DesignTimeHost in a timely fashion.
```

I can't seem to find any documentation about this error elsewhere and I have absolutely no clue as to how to circumvent it.

My `dnu restore` command completed successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this link](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/581) and thought it could help me. Luckily, the steps worked! I fixed my issue by first installing/downgrading to `dnvm 1.0.0-beta4`, I was at 6.

```
dnvm install 1.0.0-beta4
```

then explicitly pointing to that version like so,

```
dnvm use 1.0.0-beta4
```

Everything ran perfectly fine after that.

Comment: This workarounds for me using beta 5 (not 4) but still strange that VS Code requires an aging beta...

Comment: It's stuck at beta 4 at this point, as [OmniSharp](http://omnisharp.net) (which powers VS Code and other editors) as there are a number of issues that block the move beyond beta 4. You can follow the issues here: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/pull/260